# All app using friends are not coming using facebook sdk 3.23.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have implemented facebook sdk 3.23.0 for retrieving the friends who are using our app through fb login , but we are getting only some of the friends only , not all the friends who are using my app and login through facebook, is there any technical glitch we are facing from our code or facebook account settings we don't know , please let me know root cause of this problem ,

Here is the following code to retrieve the friends list , who are using our app

```
Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session,
                    new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {


                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                                com.facebook.Response response) {
                            // If the response is successful
                            Log.d(TAG, "users::********* " + users);
                            // Log.d(TAG, "users.size:: "+users.size());
                            Log.i("INFO", response.toString());
                            ArrayList<FbUser> fbUserList = new ArrayList<FbUser>();


                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation. You will only get friends that granted user_friends permission to the app

Comment: How to request for user_friends permission in fb login dialog ??

Comment: provide your code for fb login

Answer (score 1):

```
 **Try this maybe its help you change tag as your requierment **


new GraphRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                           // "/me/friends",
                            //"me/taggable_friends",
                            "me/invitable_friends",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                    try {
                                        JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                                        Log.e(TAG,"Json Array Length "+rawName.length());
                                        Log.e(TAG,"Json Array "+rawName.toString());


                                        for (int i = 0; i < rawName.length(); i++) {
                                            JSONObject c = rawName.getJSONObject(i);




                                            String name = c.getString("name");
                                            Log.e(TAG, "JSON NAME :"+name);

                                            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("picture");
                                            Log.e(TAG,""+phone.getString("data"));

                                            JSONObject jsonObject = phone.getJSONObject("data");

                                            String url = jsonObject.getString("url").toString();
                                            Log.e(TAG,"@@@@"+jsonObject.getString("url").toString());


                                        }



                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                    ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: if u not get proper result  just try to change   // "/me/friends",
                            //"me/taggable_friends",
                            "me/invitable_friends",  u will get

Comment: you should not just change to taggable_friends or invitable_friends. those endpoints are only there for very specific tasks (tagging friends and inviting friends to a game with canvas).

Comment: And if you doesn't have this permissions you won't receive data